# DocuSign invalid_grant error

Tags: docusignapi

Code Received by Get URL below:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=1590cb04-f976-4b54-897d-157f5a711ed0&state=x39pm23rtf23&redirect_uri=https://dev.coplsaas.com.au/brokerdev/webservice/whservice/getdscode
```

then used received code in POST request to access token with below request

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
HOST: account-d.docusign.com
authorization: Basic MTU5MGNiMDQtZjk3Ni00YjU0LTg5N2QtMTU3ZjVhNzExZWQwOmQxNmY4MWM0LTI5OTktNGMwOC04M2E0LTBiNWZkMGQ0NWFmMA==
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=ARd6NkNlsuk_YG75ReDu9eQB0; __RequestVerificationToken_L01l0=AbHSxThtrkGESzjnwo0t1c4B0; mest=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IkhTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiZWUyMDVlYjctYWJiMS00MmRiLTlmNjktZWFmMTg3ZThjZTczIn0.AQcAAAABAAIAAgDOEodJwVSyT4aBM16dnM1UDQAkAAAAYTFiODA4ZDktNGRhNi00ODM0LTgzOTItNGY0OWI2MDZmYTQ3FQABAAAAEgACAAAAAwAAAHRzdgsAAABpbnRlcmFjdGl2ZTAAgGs6FN6p1UgIAAAqazTgqdVI.XdbTt-fuOvAGJZ068I9T9GvA6YhmeW3Uv4RfhZPzoOA
content-length: 656

grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQkAAAABAAYABwCAcToxpqrVSAgAgP3AeKaq1UgCAM4Sh0nBVLJPhoEzXp2czVQVAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAADQAkAAAAMTU5MGNiMDQtZjk3Ni00YjU0LTg5N2QtMTU3ZjVhNzExZWQwMACAcToxpqrVSBIAAQAAAAsAAABpbnRlcmFjdGl2ZQ.KCF4tKuyh2AhA_H2FGh5ps89lT82go376xigC_lvtE6W20FonRRsiWM8CL6Bie8iS7miorenX9nVaAP-We4qKjmP1vBwp_yMujltr46Oq8Bt43l2acTgIh0Ne9yUf2C5ER1CF0nY1lusdS_UrgbEDoR_ZuDm2yuDtF2CPJtSMxjuZjEm9pgGOr7jQOCuTcwQLJA0OpmP1Dth7yzodkt50bh3Tfk3M4LxQ-xOMo_VnBTsxW_Ybu29R7ACV1nUdXMabrJQ-qtddRNULQXvXCD-ynpHu6GU0CwzRNeph6YhfRgbdB4ptWkb6XWcG3gkCpx8yaxn7glt58OjkQDi2v8Abw
```

but facing error below:

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Code returned by DocuSign after login is one time use and valid for 300 seconds. So I hope your callback URL - https://dev.coplsaas.com.au/brokerdev/webservice/whservice/getdscode is not using this code again and again. I was successfully able to generate AccessToken for my username with your code.

Comment: Amit thanks for reply. I am confused with these two statements.. 1- "Code returned by DocuSign after login is one time use and valid for 300 seconds." 2- "I was successfully able to generate AccessToken for my username with your code.". If code is valid for 300 seconds then how you generate access token with my code?

Comment: I think issue was with code expiry within 300 seconds. I generate the code and used this code within 50 seconds aprox. to get access token and i got the token successfully without any change in my process. 
Awesome Amit. You saved my 2nd day :) -  thanks again.

Comment: What I meant by your code means, your URL and your Authorization header value. I regenerated the code sent back by DocuSign, and it worked fine for me. Its good you were able to fix the issue. We should never cache or save this code sent back from DocuSign, use it as soon as you receive it to generate the accesstoken.